# Place flyout at a point?

Tags: c#, uwp, flyout

In a uwp app, is it possible to show a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.FlyoutBase object in relation to a particular point, as opposed to a FrameworkElement object?

In other words, instead of

```
flyout.ShowAt(some frameworkElement);
```

I want something like

```
flyout.ShowAt(some frameworkElement, x, y).
```

I realize I could create a dummy FrameworkElement and do it that way, then remove the dummy when the flyout is removed.  But that seems a little heavyweight.

Comment: This is for sure availabe with *MenuFlyout*, though seems like *FlyoutBase* lacks method showing at particular point.

Answer (score -1):

Romasz comment above had the correct answer. If the flyout is in fact a MenuFlyout, cast it to that class, then call.

```
Windows.Foundation.Point point = whatever;// your point here
menuFlyout.ShowAt(frameworkElement, point);
```